# How to Set, Retrieve and Unset Session Variables in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, core-session

What is the equivalent for session in Magento 1

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyValue('test');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsMyValue();
```

Same in Magento 2?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found the equivalent way for this in Magento2:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyValue('test');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsMyValue();
```

Set/Get/Unset Value in Core Session:

```
protected $_coreSession;

public function __construct(
    -----
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession
    ){
    $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
    ----
}

public function setValue(){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    $this->_coreSession->setMessage('The Core session');
}

public function getValue(){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    return $this->_coreSession->getMessage();
}

public function unSetValue(){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    return $this->_coreSession->unsMessage();
}
```

By this way we can set custom values if our session value is not related to below sessions:

- \Magento\Backend\Model\Session
- \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session
- \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
- \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
- \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Session

Comment: Nice explanation!

Comment: @Sarfaraz, can we set session in controller and we can access in block file?

Comment: can we set integer value?, i am getting below error, Object of class Magento\\Framework\\Session\\Generic\\Interceptor could not be converted to string

Answer (score 65):

In magento 2 there is no more `core/session`.
There are these ones though (may be others also):

- `\Magento\Backend\Model\Session`
- `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session`
- `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session`
- `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session`
- `\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Session`

You need to create a dependency for the session you need in your block or controller or whatever.
Let's take for example `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session`.

```
protected $catalogSession;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession, 
    ....
){
    ....
    $this->catalogSession = $catalogSession;
    ....
}
```

Then you can use the catalog session inside the class like this:

```
$this->catalogSession->setMyValue('test');
$this->catalogSession->getMyValue();
```

**[EDIT]**
You should not use sessions in templates.
You should create wrappers in the block class that the templates can use in order to set/get values.

Using the example above, create the methods in the block

```
public function setSessionData($key, $value)
{
    return $this->catalogSession->setData($key, $value);
}

public function getSessionData($key, $remove = false)
{
    return $this->catalogSession->getData($key, $remove);
}
```

But if you really want to use the session in the template you can just create a wrapper in your block for getting the session:

```
public function getCatalogSession()
{
    return $this->catalogSession;
}
```

Then you can do this in the template:

```
$this->getCatalogSession()->setMyValue('test');
$this->getCatalogSession()->getMyValue();
```

Comment: how to use session in phtml file?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya. See my update.

Comment: How to set timelife of each session declare above, @Marius

Comment: @Bill. I don't know

Comment: @Marius I think you forgot to mention how to unset session variable. So please comment regarding it. Is it similar Magento 1.9.x.x or else?

Comment: Yep. It's like in 1.9. Use `unsMyValue`

Comment: You can unset by using below sample code as per @Marius update:
$this->getCatalogSession()->unsMyValue();

Answer (score 9):

**These are all session types in Magento 2**

```
1)  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session //vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Session.php

2) \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Session //vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Session.php

3) \Magento\Persistent\Model\Session //vendor/magento/module-persistent/Model/Session.php

4) \Magento\Customer\Model\Session //vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Session.php

5) \Magento\Backend\Model\Session //vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Session.php

6) \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session //vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Session.php
```

As per Magento 2 ECGM2 coding standard you first use session class then you can pass it into constructor otherwise this error will be shown

> Session object MUST NOT be requested in constructor. It can only be passed as a method argument.

Here is how you can set and get data in session

```
namespace vendor\module\..;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Session as CatalogSession;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface as CoreSession

class ClassName {
    ...

    protected $_coreSession;
    protected $_catalogSession;
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        ....
        CoreSession $coreSession,
        CatalogSession $catalogSession,
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        ....
    ){
        ....
        $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
        $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;

        ....
    }

    public function getCoreSession() 
    {
        return $this->_coreSession;
    }

    public function getCatalogSession() 
    {
        return $this->_catalogSession;
    }

    public function getCustomerSession() 
    {
        return $this->_customerSession;
    }

    public function getCheckoutSession() 
    {
        return $this->_checkoutSession;
    }
}
```

**To set value**

```
$this->getCustomerSession()->setMyValue('YourValue');
```

**To get value**

```
$this->getCustomerSession()->getMyValue();
```

**For Unset session value**

```
$this->getCustomerSession()->unsMyValue();
```

Comment: @RobbieAverill If you found any solution from other sites you can share here on StackOverflow that's not called copy past. it's called R&D. Do you Understand?

Comment: That's fine, but you should attribute your sources when doing so

Comment: @RobbieAverill, Yes you are right. Thank you for the suggestion. I updated my answer.

Comment: I am getting warning while use a customerSession "Session object MUST NOT be requested in constructor. It can only be passed as a method argument." How to solve it ?

Comment: @SanjayGohil check my updated answer. first use session class and pass into constructor to avoid this error ""Session object MUST NOT be requested in constructor. It can only be passed as a method argument"

Comment: @SanjayGohil You can check my answer at https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/192304/35758

Comment: @PrincePatel: Can you please guide me through this, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195914/magento-2-how-to-add-some-data-into-checkout-session

Comment: @PrincePatel, I have set the session in controller, tried accessing in block file, value returning null for me

Comment: @PrincePatel, i am getting below error, Object of class Magento\\Framework\\Session\\Generic\\Interceptor could not be converted to string when i tried to set integer value in session

Comment: @PrincePatel, $this->_coreSession->start(); is it compulsory to use start there?

Comment: @jafarpinjar No, not compulsory to set or get value from the session.