# Magento 2: How to add extra variable in session for Cart

Tags: magento2, cart, custom, session, quote

I already referred

[How to Set, Retrieve and Unset Session Variables in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94265/how-to-set-retrieve-and-unset-session-variables-in-magento-2)

When a user clicks on "Add To Cart" button. I would like to Add One Additional Variable in Cart Quote Session.

How to set it & where can I do this may be Observer not sure?

Comment: you have to do observer for it and inside observer you have to call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Below Code in your Custom Module to Set, Unset Session

```
protected $_checkoutSession;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        

    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    array $data = []
)
{        

    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


public function getCheckoutSession() 
{
    return $this->_checkoutSession;
}
```

Now, we set and get session from template (.phtml) file.

```
$block->getCheckoutSession()->setTestData('123');
echo $block->getCheckoutSession()->getTestData() . '<br />'; // output: 123
```

Unset session

```
$block->getCheckoutSession()->unsTestData();
```

From checkout session, we can fetch quote information.

```
// get checkout session data
echo $block->getCheckoutSession()->getQuoteId();
print_r($block->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote()->getData());
```

Comment: Would like to set Extra Variable with Each Product. Suppose there are 3 products in Cart. Then it's gonna set with Each Product

Comment: you will get same variable whatever you are setting in set data you will get only  data . its static data only Just get & Set . if you want dynamic then you have to create product attribute & get those data dynamic

Comment: It's work like a charm. Thanks @Ankit Jaiswal

Comment: Great Ankit Shah :)