# Correct way to obtain a session object?

Tags: magento2, checkout, session

I'm writing a payment module for Magento 2 right now and I'm checking it against the 
"Magento Extension Quality Program Coding Standard" CodeSniffer
(https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp).

For every of my classes that are using a (checkout) session object, the CodeSniffer responds with the following warning:

```
Session object MUST NOT be requested in constructor. It can only be passed as a method argument.
```

I'm getting the session object in the following way:

```
/**
 * Checkout session object
 *
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
 */
protected $checkoutSession;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param  \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession)
{
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}
```

Is there a correct way to obtain the session object? 
I couldn't find anything in the Magento 2 core code.
I could only find code where it is used in exactly the same way I use it.

Comment: U have missed `protected $checkoutSession;` before Constructor

Comment: It's there, I just didn't show it in this example-code. I added it to the example for better understandability

Comment: same issue here, share it if any one have solution

Comment: See: https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp/issues/35

Answer (score 4):

Magento Docs are saying

> If a class’s constructor is particularly resource-intensive, this can lead to unnecessary performance impact when another class depends on it, if the expensive object does not end up being needed during a particular request.
>
> Magento has a solution for this situation: proxies. Proxies extend other classes to become lazy-loaded versions of them. That is, a real instance of the class a proxy extends is created only after one of the class’s methods is actually called. A proxy implements the same interface as the original class and so can be used as a dependency anywhere the original class can. Unlike its parent, a proxy has only once dependency: the object manager.
>
> Proxies are generated code and therefore do not need to be manually written. (See Code generation for more information.) Simply reference a class in the form \Original\Class\Name\Proxy, and the class is generated if it does not exist.

[Magento 2 Proxies](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/proxies.html)

So, in your case

```
/**
 * Checkout session object
 *
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Proxy
 */
protected $checkoutSession;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param  \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Proxy $checkoutSession
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Proxy $checkoutSession)
{
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}
```

Note **\Proxy** suffix for the object **\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session**

Answer (score 2):

As the warning indicates:

```
Session object MUST NOT be requested in the constructor
```

You should use proxies instead.

You can find out more about proxy objects here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/proxies.html

Answer (score 1):

Magento restricts injecting Sessions and Proxies directly in constructor.

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/coding-standards/technical-guidelines/

2.5. Proxies and interceptors MUST NEVER be explicitly requested in constructors.

9.10. The Request, Session, and Cookie objects MUST NOT be injected in an object constructor. They MUST be passed only as method arguments.

Session interface should be injected in constructor, proxy should be connected in di.xml

So, you need to

1. Inject Session interface
2. Inject Session as proxy

Example how to inject session and follow all the standards:

```
<?php

namespace Some\Module;

class ClassName {
  public function __construct(
    private readonly \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session)
  {
  }
}
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Some\Module\ClassName">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="session" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Model\Session\Proxy</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

P.S.

You can still find lots of places where Magento 2 doesn't follow its own standards and inject session directly.

Answer (score 0):

As per Magento 2 ECGM2 coding standard you first use session class then you can pass it into constuctor otherwise this error will be shown

> Session object MUST NOT be requested in constructor. It can only be passed as a method argument.

**Example:**

```
namespace vendor\module\..;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class ClassName {
    ...

    protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        ....
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        ....
    ){
        ....
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: @Price Patel I still get the above error on using this code. Any solution?This is my code :
namespace ...;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class Test
{
    private $checkoutSession;

    private $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        CustomerSession $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }