# Put variable from phtml to an observer

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer

I'm trying to send a **variable** from a **phtml** to an observer through an event observer. Is that possible?

**Note:** variables are defined by a **script** in the **phtml**.

**Edit:** 
The name of event is "`checkout_cart_product_add_after`".
In the script I have some like this:

```
function cambio_telas(event){
    telaactual = event.data.tela;
}
```

And I want to send the var "telaactual" to the observer:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

  $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
  $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

  $additionalOptions = array(
    array(
      'label' => 'Tela',
      'value' => 'tela02'
    )
 }
```

In short, I need to apply the variable "`currentdata`" to value in "`$ aditionalOptions`"

Comment: Please add some more information like which event, variable. Also add `script` to get clear idea.

Comment: thx for you recomendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getData()` and `setData()`

**in phtml :**

`$myVal = 'hello';`

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('value1', $myVal); //save data in value1
```

**in Observer :**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('value1'); //you get the saved value in value1
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsetData('value1'); // you empty the value1 value from session for the next use.
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, I didn't see that you want the Magento 2, there was no tag, however I'm not Magento 2, but you can follow this tuto:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/94267/48355

Comment: Hi this works for magento 2.1??? .. i need some configuration?? when i use Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('value1', $myVal); //save data in value1
 the page crash.

Comment: Please, look my update

Comment: :) nice, now i have defined ´function getCheckoutSession()´ in my block, but ´$this->getCheckoutSession()->getMyValue();´ no work in observer... 
I think I missed something but I do not know.