# Magento 2: How to add some data into checkout session?

Tags: magento2, checkout, checkoutsession

I have successfully added new checkout form, following the instructions are given on:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html

When I submit the form i get the data in,

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form'
], function(Component) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // component initialization logic
            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Form submit handler
         *
         * This method can have any name.
         */
        onSubmit: function() {
            // trigger form validation
            this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
            this.source.trigger('customCheckoutForm.data.validate');

            // verify that form data is valid
            if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                // data is retrieved from data provider by value of the customScope property
                var formData = this.source.get('customCheckoutForm');
                // do something with form data
                console.dir(formData);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Now I want to add this **formData** in checkout session so that I can insert my custom fields in DB when the user places the order. Where and How should I make the HTTP call?