# How to use session and pass some value to phtml file to phtml file?

Tags: magento2, session

I want to pass some value in phtml file to another phtml file somewhere else

as an example 1.phtml file like below

```
<?php

$inputMessage = 'Hello World';
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setWelcomeMessage($inputMessage);

?>
```

and 2.phtml file like below

```
<?php

$outputMessage = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getWelcomeMessage();
echo $this->__($outputMessage);
        
?>
```

if I use something like this it will give an error like below

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage' not found in
> C:\xamppp\htdocs\iconmirror\app\code\Codazon\Slideshow\view\frontend\templates\slideshow.phtml:92
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xamppp\htdocs\iconmirror\vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(59):
> include() #1
> C:\xamppp\htdocs\iconmirror\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(255):
> Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Codazon\Slideshow\Block\Widget\Slideshow),
> 'C:/xamppp/htdoc...', Array) #2
> C:\xamppp\htdocs\iconmirror\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(279):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('C:/xamppp/htdoc...')
>
> ## 3 C:\xamppp\htdocs\iconmirror\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(659):
>
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() #4
> C:\xamppp\htdocs\iconmirror\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(542):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() #5
> C:\xamppp\htdocs\iconmirror\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(518):
> Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderB in
> C:\xamppp\htdocs\iconmirror\app\code\Codazon\Slideshow\view\frontend\templates\slideshow.phtml
> on line 92

please help me with this im new to magento 2

Comment: Are you looking for Magento 1 solution or Magento 2? You have shared code for Magento 1 and tagged question with magento 2.

Comment: oh im using magento 2 how can I do that in magento 2 i just found above code in google thats why i try that its not work

Comment: it will not work because code you are using is 
Magento 1 and implementing it in Magento 2.

Comment: can u help me with how to do this in magento 2. it would be really helpful

Comment: please check this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94265/how-to-set-retrieve-and-unset-session-variables-in-magento-2

Comment: how can u use that in phtml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write block in your custom module.

> Path: Vendor/Module/Block/Customer/Links.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

class Links extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Check customer is logged in or not
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn();
    }

    /**
     * Check customer is logged in or not
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getCustomerName()
    {
        return $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
    }
}
```

> Your Vendor\Module/view/frontend/templates/Customer/links.phtml

```
<?php if($block->isLoggedIn()): ?>
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="<?= $this->getUrl('customer/account/logout'); ?>" class="action primary"><?= __('logout'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div><?= __('Hi, %1', $block->getCustomerName()); ?><a href="<?= $this->getUrl('customer/account/edit'); ?>"><?= __('Edit'); ?></a></div>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please accept as answer if it helped you. It will help others too.

Comment: so cant i pass value module to module because in your case its passing value same module block to view

Comment: You can write same block code in helper file and can call helper file in any module's template.