# How to destroy custom session value after X minutes in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, session

As I know there isn't a `core/session` in Magento 2 [[source]](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/94267/9169), I've created a custom session using `customer/session` as given below:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ....
) {
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    ...
}
public function execute() {
    $this->customerSession->setOtp(5); // To set session value
    $this->customerSession->getOtp();  // To get session value
}
```

`$this->customerSession->destroy();` will destroy whole customer session, which I do not want.
 Is it possible to destroy this particular `otp` session value automatically after 30 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove/unset custom session via 'uns' prefix.

$this->customerSession->unsOtp();

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to set the time after which it will be automatically destroyed?

Comment: I think you need to create a custom script and set this script to cron. Cron will run that script every 30min. http://thisinterestsme.com/expire-php-sessions/ this reference link will help you to check the time and unset session.

Comment: I think there should be a more simpler solution to automatically unset this value?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Else you can use cookies that will be upset at the particular time.