# Can you Call a function definted in a block from the observer?

Tags: magento2

Can you Call a function defined in a block from the observer in magento2?

My purpose is to assign a session variable in the observer and then later retrieve it in a phtml.

Thanking you in advance.

**Observer**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Customer;

use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Authenticated implements ObserverInterface
{
  protected $_responseFactory;
protected $_url;
protected $email;

protected $_coreSession;

public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession

) {
    $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->_url = $url;
    $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
  //  $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
}

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
      {
        //get object method

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer = $event->getCustomer();

  $email=$customer->getEmail();

    $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "53252",
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:53252/api/Account/Login",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n\t\"Email\":\"$email\",\n\t\"Password\":\"$email\"\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
    "postman-token: f2d5833b-07f0-9ecc-ca24-94dd9fc58a66"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Display');
$blockObj->getCatalogSession()->setMyName('Mageplaza');
curl_close($curl);
$json = json_decode($response, true);
//$this->customerSession->setMyValue($json);
//$this->customerSession->getMyValue();
$this->_coreSession->start();
    $this->_coreSession->setMessage('The Core session');
if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {

  //echo $response;
  if($json['Response']!='FOUND'){
  $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('test/page/view');
         $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
       }
  else {
    return $this;
  }
}
exit;
}
//$redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('[test]/[page]/[[view]');
//$this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();

//return $this;

  }
```

**Block**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Display extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_catalogSession;
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function _prepareLayout()
        {
            return parent::_prepareLayout();
        }

        public function getCatalogSession()
        {
            return $this->_catalogSession;
        }

        public function getCustomerSession()
        {
            return $this->_customerSession;
        }

        public function getCheckoutSession()
        {
            return $this->_checkoutSession;
        }    
    public function sayHello()
    {
        return __('Hello World');
    }
    public function getValue(){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    return $this->_coreSession->getMessage();
}
}
```

**phtml**

```
<?php
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Display');
echo $blockObj->sayHello();
//$block->getCatalogSession()->setMyName('Mageplaza');
echo $block->getCatalogSession()->getMyName() . '<br />';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$renderBlock = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Blocks\YourBlockName');
echo $renderBlock->sayHello();
```

Comment: I wanted to set the variable in the observer and get the same variable and value from the phtml. Could you tell me how to do it individually ?

Comment: you can use by session concept right?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94265/how-to-set-retrieve-and-unset-session-variables-in-magento-2  @Prince Patel answer might be helpful try and let me know

Comment: I tried,I declared the session in the observer, but couldn't access the same in the phtml. Do let me know if I did something wrong