# Magento 2 pass data from template html to phtml file

Tags: magento2, template, phtml

So far I have created file `MyModule/ProductAlert/view/frontend/email/stock.html` -

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Products back in stock alert"}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var alertGrid|raw":"Alert Data Grid",
"var email":"Customer Email",
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/footer_template\"":"Email Footer Template",
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/header_template\"":"Email Header Template"
} @-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

{{var alertGrid|raw}}

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

And I would like to pass my variable `email` to .phtml file in 
`MyModule/ProductAlert/view/frontend/templates/email/stock.phtml` and call it there -

```
    <?php
use MyModule\ProductAlert\Block\Email\Stock;

/** @var $block Stock */
?>

    <?php if ($_products = $block->getProducts()): ?>
        <?php foreach ($_products as $_product): ?>
            <p><?= __('Hello!') ?></p>
            <p>Your email: <?php $block->getData('email') ?></p> // Email should be here
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Currently it returns me nothing. How can I achieve that? Thank you!

Comment: have you tried {{var email}} instead of $block-getData(email)? . Some code is missing

Comment: @RafaelShkembi if I call this in .html file, then it works yes, but I want to pass that email variable from .html file and use it in .phtml file. If I call {{var email}} in .phtml file then it returns "{{var email}}"

Comment: I'm not sure if you can achieve that but you can try using sessions. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94265/how-to-set-retrieve-and-unset-session-variables-in-magento-2

Comment: In `stock.phtml` file display dynamic email data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method in `MyModule\ProductAlert\Block\Email\Stock`
You need to inject `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession`, class to get customer Email.

```
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    ...
}

public function getCustomerEmail()
{
    return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail(); 
}
```

And in your **.phtml**, you call it **`$block->getCustomerEmail()`**

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a layout handle for it.

> MyModule/ProductAlert/view/frontend/email/stock.html

```
<tr class="email-information">
    <td>
        {{layout handle="product_alert_email_stock" items=$items  area="frontend"}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the above code, I have declared variable `items=$items`

create block file for a layout handle.

> MyModule\ProductAlert\Block\Email\Stock

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\ProductAlert\Block\Email\Stock;

class Items extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

}
```

Now in phtml file write below code.

> MyModule/ProductAlert/view/frontend/templates/email/stock.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->getItems()) :
    foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item) :
    print_r($_item);
    endforeach;
endif; ?>
```

You can get data using `$this->getItems()` because we have create variable `items=$items`

I hope it helps!