# Magento 2 echo newsletter subscriber's email in frontend after subscription

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, newsletter, newsletter-subscriber

How can we display a newsletter subscriber's email address in the frontend after they subscribe for a newsletter.

Currently, Magento 2 displays a message "Thank you for your subscription".

We need this changed to "Thank you for your subscription. A confirmation email will be sent to youremail@example.com within 10 minutes"

Comment: I think it's better to override or use Plugin `Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom module as below for override the newsletter success message.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Newsletter"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction" type="Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Rewrite/Magento/Newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber;

class NewAction extends \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction
{
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {
            $email = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('email');

            try {
                $this->validateEmailFormat($email);
                $this->validateGuestSubscription();
                $this->validateEmailAvailable($email);

                $subscriber = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
                if ($subscriber->getId()
                    && $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED
                ) {
                    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                        __('This email address is already subscribed.')
                    );
                }

                $status = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
                if ($status == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The confirmation request has been sent.'));
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Thank you for your subscription. A confirmation email will be sent to '.$email.' within 10 minutes'));
                }
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException(
                    $e,
                    __('There was a problem with the subscription: %1', $e->getMessage())
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong with the subscription.'));
            }
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
    }

}
```

I have updated this line in the above file.

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Thank you for your subscription. A confirmation email will be sent to '.$email.' within 10 minutes'));
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Is it possible to save that email in a session? How can we do that from here?

Comment: Yes, you can, Check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/209343/59677

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use Plugin. And avoiding overriding.

**app/code/Vendor/Newsletter/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber">
        <plugin name="customMessage" type="Vendor\Newsletter\Plugin\Controller\Subscriber" sortOrder="999"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Newsletter/Plugin/Controller/Subscriber.php**

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Newsletter\Plugin\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\MessageInterface;

class Subscriber
{
    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    private $messageManager;

    /**
     * Subscriber constructor.
     * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $this->addCustomMessages($subject);
        return $result;
    }

    private function addCustomMessages($subject)
    {
        $email = (string)$subject->getRequest()->getPost('email');
        $messages = $this->messageManager->getMessages();
        $count = $messages->getCountByType(MessageInterface::TYPE_SUCCESS);
        if ($count) {
            $messageItems = $messages->getItems();
            //$text = __('Thank you for your subscription.');
            foreach ($messageItems as $key => $message) {
                if ($message->getType() == MessageInterface::TYPE_SUCCESS) {
                    //Need to check more cases
                    $messages->deleteMessageByIdentifier($message->getIdentifier());
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                        __('Thank you for your subscription. A confirmation email will be sent to %1 within 10 minutes', $email)
                    );
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

**[Warning]** Using this way can cause the losing success messages. We should check more cases to validate the correct message.